# Finding intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have these 2 subspaces:

V = ⟨(1,1,2),(-1,0,1)⟩ and W = ⟨(7,3,−1),(-1,1,5)⟩

I need to find V ∩ W, however I didn't really understand how to do it. Would really appreciate an explanation! Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The subspaces $V$ and $W$ span planes, say $P_V$ (that spanned by $V$) and $P_W$. Find the equation of each plane and see if you can reduce this to the equation of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: A vector $(x,y,z)$ is in $V \cap W$ if it is in $V$ and it is in $W$. This implies that

$$(x,y,z) = c_1(1,1,2) + c_2(-1,0,1)= c_3(7,3,-1) + c_4(-1,1,5).$$

From the system of equations you get from this, you should be able to figure out the form of the vectors in $V \cap W.$